# Appending to a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to append data I fetched from server to a div tag, but I can't get it to work. That's HTML with a div tag to which I'd like to append data from the JS code.

HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
```

And here is JavaScript code. I would like to replace document.write with a function that will append data to a div tag.

JS:

```
function initialize() {
$.getJSON('http://www.wawhost.com/izdelava-mobilne-aplikacije-2-del/fetch.php?callback=?', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        document.write('<img src="' + data[i].image + '" />' + data[i].title + data[i].description + '<br>');
    }
});
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GDxtf/

I just started learning JavaScript. Help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: By *append*, do you mean *insert into*?  If so, you could use getElementById() and innerHTML.

Comment: @David That doesn't work for me because it keeps replacing the data. Thank you anyways! :)

Comment: `var e = getElementById("text").innerHTML = e.innterHTML + "<img...>"`  Does something like this not work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GDxtf/2/ it doesn't, but I might not doing something right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code in the bottom of your HTML document, right before `</body>`:

```
<script>
// If you're not using an HTML5 doctype, use <script type="text/javascript> instead of just <script>

$(function () {

    $targetDiv = $("#text");
    $.getJSON('http://www.wawhost.com/izdelava-mobilne-aplikacije-2-del/fetch.php?callback=?', function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var $div = $("<div />");
            var $img = $("<img />");

            $img.attr("src", data[i].image);
            $img.appendTo($div);

            var $title = $("<h2>" + data[i].title + "</h2>");
            $title.appendTo($div);

            var $description = $("<p>" + data[i].description + "</p>");
            $description.appendTo($div);

            $div.appendTo($targetDiv);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: You're welcome :) Tip tip tip: Read [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) if you've got similar questions. It's really helpful to understand how it all works